# Convergence of integral

Tags: calculus, integration

If one definite integral equals to 0, does that mean that the integral does not converge? Thanks.

For example, integrate $\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos (2x-\pi)}$ from $\frac{\pi}{6}$ to  $\frac{\pi}{3}$, so the result is 0. Does that mean the integral does not converge or is there any where to know whether one integral does not converge ?

Comment: If the integral takes a finite value, it converges. There is nothing special about the value zero.

Comment: What meaning of finite value ?

Comment: If your integral is in absolute value $<\infty$.

Comment: Remember that the definite integral also corresponds to the area between the curve and the $x$ axis. If half of the area is below the axis and the second half is above the axis, then the integral is $0$. But, for the case you give, there is another problem around $\pi/4$.